# Find Windows Task Bar in 3 monitor setup

Tags: java, monitor, taskbar

I have a 3 monitor setup. I might have the Windows Task Bar on the 2nd or 3rd monitor.

How would I find on which monitor the Task Bar is placed using Java? I have tried looking for a Java API to help but could not find one.

Comment: The 'task bar' is not a Java concept. Are you talking about the Window's Task Bar?

Comment: Yes I am talking to windows taskbar

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the task bar is always on the primary monitor, but I think that it is.

You can get the monitor configuration using [`GraphicsDevice`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html).

This should dump the current configuration of your screens. I think the primary screen will have X and Y values of 0 and other screens will have either negative or positive values depending on their position in relation to the primary screen.

I can't verify because I've only got one screen and I'm on Linux, but it should hopefully get you going in the right direction.

```
public class ScreenTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GraphicsEnvironment environment = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        for(GraphicsDevice device : environment.getScreenDevices()) {
            System.out.println(device.getIDstring());
            for(GraphicsConfiguration configuration : device.getConfigurations()) {
                System.out.println(configuration.getBounds());
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output for one screen under Ubuntu:

```
:0.0
java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=1920,height=1080]
java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=1920,height=1080]
< 181 more of these >
java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=1920,height=1080]
```

Comment: I am also a linux user, but I used to do a lot of windows dev a lifetime ago. This unfortunately will not work due to the fact that the taskbar can be placed on any of the 3 screens ( not just display 0) , it can also be setup to span all availible screens ( as well as be placed on the side or top of the screen.

Comment: It does't work below is answer I get for 2 monitor setup, windows taskbar could be on any of the monitor 




run:
\Display0
java.awt.Rectangle[x=1280,y=0,width=1280,height=1024]

\Display1
java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=1280,height=1024]

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)